# Regex needs to select more then one but its not working

Tags: regex

If I have this text

> SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = >'/[0-9]/'< AND u = >'/[a-z]/'<

I should get the result:

```
[1] => /[0-9]/
[2] => /[a-z]/
```

So, I have this regex;

```
\>(.+)\<
```

But now it selects:

```
'/[0-9]/'< AND u = >'/[a-z]/'<
```

Why??!?!? I end the string with a < so that should be the end?

Comment: Your regex pattern is greedy. Make it lazy by adding a `?` at the end. Also, you don't need to escape `>` and `>`s: `>(.+?)<`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**Reluctant quantifiers**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) to use Laziness Instead of Greediness.

```
>(.+?)<
```

`.+` is a **Greedy quantifiers** looks in greed way to match as much as possible.

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL0fN8/1)

**Note:** I think there is no need to escape `>` and `<`

---

Alternatively you can try with [**Possessive Quantifiers**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) as well.

```
>([^<]*+)<
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL0fN8/5)

Better use second option. [Want to Be Lazy? Think Twice.](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html)

Comment: Please don't use backticks for emphasis. Use bold/italics instead. See [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990), and [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135112/) discussions regarding this.